# SQL Select between 2 times that cross over days

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi i have been trying to put an SQL query together to pull data from 20:00 last night to 8 am today

what i currntly have is however this only selects between 20:00 and 24 because it's only selecting last night what would be the best way to get the results i am looking for?

```
SELECT     COUNT(CardID) AS CardCOUNT
FROM         ReaderData
WHERE     (controllerID = 28) AND (ReaderTime BETWEEN '20:00:00' AND '08:00:00') AND (CardID = 'fffffff0') AND (DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEADD(DAY, - 1, 
                  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), dtReading) = 0)
```

Comment: put the datadiff calc inside the between

Comment: it would be nice if there was sample data. But the easiest thing that comes to mind is converting the datetime to int CONVERT(INT, CAST ('2013-08-05 09:23:30' as DATETIME)) and doing a BETWEEN

Comment: I don't understand how you are getting anything at all from that query. `BETWEEN '20:00:00' AND '08:00:00'` is a negative interval so how can any row be returned using that filter?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson It's supposed to select between 8pm and 8 am so it has to be like that

Comment: ReaderIndex int
CardID nchar(10)
ReaderDate nvarchar(50)
ReaderTime nvarchar(50)
EventType nvarchar(50)
controllerID int
dtReading datetime
bProcessed bit

I take it i am not doing this query the correct way, what would that be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have split the time from the date so you have to check one time interval for yesterday and another for today.

If you are on SQL Server 2008 and have stored only the date part in `dtReading` you could use something like this.

```
select count(R.CardID) as CardCount
from ReaderData as R
where controllerID = 28 and
      (
        (
          R.dtReading = cast(dateadd(day, -1, getdate()) as date) and
          R.ReaderTime >= '20:00:00'
        ) or
        (
          R.dtReading = cast(getdate() as date) and
          R.ReaderTime < '08:00:00'
        )
      )
```

**Update**

With the time values in `dtReading` it is easier.
Remove the time part from `getdate()` by casting to `date` then add the number of hours you want to create the `datetime` values you want to compare against.

```
select count(R.CardID) as CardCount
from ReaderData as R
where controllerID = 28 and
      R.dtReading >= dateadd(hour, 20, dateadd(day, -1, cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime))) and
      R.dtReading < dateadd(hour, 8, cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime))
```

Comment: the records are sent to the database with a time stamp which looks like 2014-05-19 09:12:20.000 and the column name for that is dtReading, i don't know if that would make it any easier

Comment: Thank you very much mikael this has helped me alot!